# Moving old DNN website to IIS 8 hover menus don't work

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke, iis-8

I have been asked to move an old DNN website to a Windows 2012 R2 server.

I have managed to get it up and running but the hover menus are not appearing on the website when running on IIS 8.

This website was written with DNN version 1 using visual basic and .Net 1 but I am not currently planning to upgrade to a new version of DNN.

I have gotten the project to run in visual studio 2010 with the .Net 3.5 Framework.

Has anyone seen behavior like this before?

Also can a DNN 1 website even run on windows server 2012 R2?

[image: picture of hover menu]

Edit:

The screenshot is from the current production site where the drop down menu shows up when you hover over "Cards" for instance. On the IIS 8 server nothing happens when you hover and it the same project.

I have done an inspect element on the horizontal menu item on both versions of the web site and the elements are different in both.

Edit 2:

I have also been getting this error in the Immediate Window in Visual Studio:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in SolpartWebControls.dll`

Comment: Is that screenshot from a different version of IIS, or are you saying that the hover menus for child menus don't work?

Comment: The screenshot is from the current production site where the drop down menu shows up when you hover over "Cards" for instance. On the IIS 8 server nothing happens when you hover and it the same project.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Not in the Javascript Console but I am getting an error multiple times in the server console while I do debugging. I have added it to the question.